# VBA code loop through files in a folder based on cell ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell ranges `(A2:A6)` as department as below.

```
Department
WFM
WFA
Finance
Accounts
HR
```

And with the above department name, I have files in a specific folder.

Is it possible to loop through each files based on the cell ranges?

Googled a lot but no luck.

Hope someone will be able to put some light on how can that be accomplished.

Comment: If you google for folder content listing code then there will be several codes coming up. You need to customize it to suit your needs. My suggestion, pick a code which suits for a folder and take it from there.

Comment: give some thought to whether you are looping the contents of the range, the folder or both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VBA `dir` function to iterate over files in a particular directory.

Refer to examples 6-8 from [here](https://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-dir-function/).